# How to inject a dependency into a TableView loaded from a XIB?

Tags: swift, dependency-injection, tableview

How do i inject a date into a UITableView subclass that needs a date to run its fetchedResultsController predicate properly?

Is there must be a way to get around this with coupling my objects together. I would prefer to keep the XIB for now.

I can't override initWithCoder and initWithFrame means I have to throw away the XIB based design.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where's your code? It should be doable.

Comment: Pretty sure it's not because you override pass anything in loading from the NIB. How would you do it?

Comment: I can't help without seeing any code, but it shouldn't be difficult. There are many ways to do that. It all depends on what you've done so far. You could also explain more clearly what you have done and what you need. You've only explained isolated pieces of what you're doing, so I'm still guessing at what you need... For example, I don't understand your most recent comment.